# Ubuntu 17.04 - can't install mysql-server-5.6

Tags: ubuntu, package, apt

I searched everywhere for this one and can't get it to work.
when running:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

I get this result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.6 : Depends: initscripts but it is not installable
                    Depends: mysql-client-5.6 (>= 5.6.16-1~exp1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.6 (= 5.6.16-1~exp1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) but it is not installable or
                             file-rc (>= 0.8.16) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried:

```
sudo aptitude install mysql-server
```

which tries to solve it by:

```
     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     mysql-client-5.6 [Not Installed]                   
2)     mysql-client-core-5.6 [Not Installed]              
3)     mysql-server-5.6 [Not Installed]                   
4)     mysql-server-core-5.6 [Not Installed]
```

But this doesn't work either.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

there is nothing being held under dpkg command above command.
Also any other upgrade/update or removing/purging any mysql instances didn't help.
Thanks!

**EDIT-1**
after purging mysql* and reinstall with aptitude, I'm getting rid of some dependencies. the persisting dependencies are **initscripts**, **sysv-rc** and **file-rc**. so still struggling here.

Comment: try this apt-get install -f or this Click [here] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Already tired this post :] thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 17.04 only provides packages for MySQL 5.7 which has a range of backwards compatibility issues with code written against older MySQL versions.

Oracle maintains a list of official APT repositories for MySQL 5.6, but those repositories do not yet support Ubuntu 17.04 (as of the time of writing this post). This has been an issue that persisted across previous versions of ubuntu.

To solve this problem, start by removing/uninstalling all existing mysql modules. To get the list of installed mysql modules, use the following command:

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

Download the apt_config-debian package (`mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb`)from [Mysql Website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) and install it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
```

Create a new file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/mysql` with this content

```
Package: *
Pin: origin "repo.mysql.com"
Pin-Priority: 999
```

Run the following command to update the cache

```
sudo apt update
```

Run the following command to install MySQL

```
sudo apt install mysql-client mysql-server libmysqlclient-dev
```

You should get 5.6 versions.

This solution has been discussed more [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/39899-install-mysql-5-6-in-ubuntu-16-04), incase you want more details, or if you run into some issues.

Comment: I thought its hopeless so I moved on with Percona. Your answer sounds promising though and I promise to try it out as soon as needed and give you feedback. Regardless, I appreciate your time and effort!!

Comment: To uninstall the existing package: 
```sudo apt-get purge php7.3-mysql```